# Exception: .InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://accounts.go-ally.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, ids

I have a dotnet core 6 application , and IDS application
when I run connection this in local it works file and when I host on any server or IIS
it shows an error

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
SpanId: 82ca2a5b19214ee8
TraceId: ac73c85bca4dc4f01a21491a71f562dc
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 80000acb-0002-eb00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://accounts.go-ally.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '1/30/2024 9:42:30 AM +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://accounts.go-ally.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a problem with SSL certificate validation, the SSL certificate used by your application was not recognized as valid because it was signed by an untrusted certificate authority (CA). To resolve this issue, you need to manually add the self-signed certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on the local computer.